# Immutablejs and shouldComponentUpdate

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

Can react-redux still make use of shouldComponentUpdate if i'm using Immutable.js? The connect() method uses shallowEqual in shouldComponentUpdate() but from the Immutable.js docs i see that we have to use Immutable's own equals() method to check equality rather than the === operator (which shallowEqual uses)

Consider this:

```
const map1 = Immutable.Map({a:1, b:2, c:3});
const map2 = Immutable.Map({a:1, b:2, c:3});

map1 === map2 // returns false
map1.equals(map2) // returns true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole point of using `immutable.js` is to keep the reference when the underlying object actually don't change. The `shallowEqual` performs a quick equality check between property, that's a huge gain over deep comparing value with `immutable.equals`.

Example :

```
let state = Immutable.Map({a: 1, b:2, c:3)}

let state2 = state.set('a', 1)

state === state2  //true because Immutable returns the same reference object since there is no changes
```

In your example you explicitly allocate two different `Immutable.Map` objects so it's two different object in memory and `map1 === map2` returns `false`.